# Is there a way the i can trigger multiple popovers from on roll over area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popover

Basically I'm trying to call the same JavaScript function multiple times to trigger more than one popover.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
$('[rel="popover"]').popover({
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        var clone = $($(this).data('popover-content')).clone(true).removeClass('hide');
        return clone;
    }
}).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" rel="popover" title="Popover Title" data-placement="top"data-trigger="hover" data-popover-content="#Popover_Content">

<div id="Popover_Content" class="hide">

Popover Content

</div>

<area shape="rect" name="Rollover_Area"    coords="378,439,491,462"    href="#">


</a>
```

CSS

```
#Popover{

position: relative;

bottom: 500px;

left: 500px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking this function in this snippet code https://jsfiddle.net/68k33bqh/1/

```
function attachPopover(e){
$(e).popover({
      html:true,
      content:function(){
      var a = $(e).clone();
      attachPopover(a[0]);
      return a;
}});

}
attachPopover($('[data-toggle="popover"]')[0]);

$(document).click(function(e){
    if($('[data-toggle="popover"]').index(e.target)>-1) attachPopover(e.target);
});
```